# Swift Reload and Save Array to Plist

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I create and save the different names of the buttons in a plist file as an array ....

```
var newSpecificationTitleTextField: UITextField?
var specs : [String]
```

data?.setValue(self.specs, forKey: "NameButton")

and everything is fine until I create my button from scratch since my array is updated .....
but if I restart my app I can loaded the various names , but if i create a new button , my array in the plist does not add the new name but initializes this and I get an error
how can I retrieve the array saved and accordingly add other names ?